# How lit is this room?  pt. 1

Tags: code-golf, geometry

Related to [this question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/151501/how-lit-is-this-mountain).

A *room* is defined to be a (not necessarily convex) non-intersecting polygon, expressed as an ordered list of 2-dimensional coordinates. A sufficiently bright lightbulb is placed at a specific point inside the room, and emits light in every direction. Your task is to find the total illuminated area of the room. You may take in input in any reasonable format. The points on the polygon/room as well as the coordinates of the light source are rational numbers. They can be taken in clockwise or counterclockwise, either format is fine. The test case in the problem is given counterclockwise.

The following picture shows two example rooms, where the purplish dot represents the light source, and the shaded region represents the illuminated area.[image: A drawing of an illuminated room - shaded area is illuminated]

Test case:

```
(1/2, 18)
(1,3)
(5,1/2)
(7,5)
(12,7)
(16,3)
(15,11)
(8,19)
(3,7)
Light source located at (5,8)
Answer: 815523/6710 ≈ 121.538
```

Here is a graphical depiction of the solution to that test case. The two points that define the solution that are not on the original polygon are (55/61, 363/61) and (856/55, 357/55).  [image]

This formula may be helpful in calculating the area. [image: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoelace_formula]

Since this is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), the shortest code in bytes wins.

Comment: For those curious, part 2 might take a while to post because it'll take me forever to draw the pictures, and I also don't know how to solve it.

Comment: The points on the polygon/room as well as the coordinates of the light source are rational numbers.

Comment: Is there an upper bound on the number of vertices or should your program theoretically be able to handle an unlimited number? Also, your code-golf tag is broken. it's `[tag:code-golf]`

Comment: Your program or at least your algorithm should theoretically be able to handle an unlimited number, I can't think of a reason to arbitrarily limit the number of vertices (but I'm open to changing this if you have a specific reason why)

Comment: Ah, the good old [shoelace formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoelace_formula)!  By the way, we actually have MathJax so you needn't embed the formula as an image.

Comment: it's stolen from wikipedia, do you have a link that shows how to use MathJax?

Comment: [Meta post on finally getting MathJax back!!](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16556/67312)

Comment: Here's a mathjax version of your image (right click > show math as > TeX commands): $$\begin{align*}
\mathbf{A}&=\frac{1}{2}\left|\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}x_{i}y_{i+1}+x_{n}y_{1}-\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}x_{i+1}y_{i}-x_{1}y_{n}\right|\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\left|x_{1}y_{2}+x_{2}y_{3}+\cdots+x_{n-1}y_{n}-x_{2}y_{1}-x_{3}y_{2}-\cdots-x_{n}y_{n-1}-x_{1}y_{n}\right|
\end{align*}$$
You can use https://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php as an editor and a way to get used to mathjax, and there's [this tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) which can help

Comment: Are the points guaranteed to be ordered clockwise?

Comment: Yes, they are ordered (an unordered set of points don't form a unique nonconvex polygon)

Comment: But they could also be ordered counterclockwise. A list of points still defines the same polygon following rotation or reversal of the list.

Comment: Yes, they can be guaranteed to be ordered clockwise, then. The test case is ordered counterclockwise, but I think this falls under “any reasonable format.”

Comment: OK, I had wondered this about the first Monte Carlo answer, but now that we have a second one: should these even be considered as valid answers? It seems they are solving a slightly different challenge than the one described.

Comment: I also wondered this, but I thought it wasn't my place to comment on that because I don't know very much about what this community considers acceptable.

Comment: @bushdid911 I think you can decide; it's your challenge. For example, you could require a minimum accuracy in a given time limit. (Maybe not for this challenge, but for part 2.)

Answer (score 12):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 388 <s>398</s> <s>408</s> <s>409</s> <s>415</s> <s>417</s> <s>493</s> bytes

---

To make it more accurate, increase `n`

```python
from random import*
u=uniform
c=lambda A,B,C:(C[1]-A[1])*(B[0]-A[0])>(B[1]-A[1])*(C[0]-A[0])
I=lambda A,B,C,D:c(A,C,D)!=c(B,C,D)and c(A,B,C)!=c(A,B,D)
def a(l,v,n=9**6,s=0):
 g=lambda i:(min(x[i]for x in v),max(x[i]for x in v))
 for _ in'x'*n:
  h=((u(*g(0)),u(*g(1))),l);s+=any([I(*f,*h)for f in list(zip(v,v[1:]+[v[0]]))])^1
 return(abs(g(0)[0]-g(0)[1])*abs(g(1)[0]-g(1)[1]))*float(s/n)
```

Basic Monte-Carlo approach.  Steps listed below.

1. Find x and y ranges that the shape occupies.
2. Create a list of edges created by the vertices
3. Iterate a large number of times (the more the better)
4. Create a random point (j,k) inside the x,y range.
5. Check if any of the edges intercept with the line-segment created by the light and the random point. If any of the edges intercept, increment the variable `s`
6. Divide `s` by the total numbers, then multiply by the total range area.

### Ungolfed version:

```python
import random

def ccw(A,B,C):
    return (C[1]-A[1])*(B[0]-A[0]) > (B[1]-A[1])*(C[0]-A[0])

def intersect(A,B,C,D):
    return ccw(A,C,D) != ccw(B,C,D) and ccw(A,B,C) != ccw(A,B,D)

def lit_area(light, vertices):
    # points: list of points
    # i     : x => i=0
    #       : y => i=1
    get_range = lambda i: (min(x[i] for x in vertices), max(x[i] for x in vertices))
    xr = abs(get_range(0)[0] - get_range(0)[1])
    yr = abs(get_range(1)[0] - get_range(1)[1])

    edges = list(zip(vertices, vertices[1:] + [vertices[0]]))

    num_sims = 1000000

    num_successes = 0
    for _ in range(num_sims):
        guess_x = random.uniform(*get_range(0))
        guess_y = random.uniform(*get_range(1))

        light_guess_line = ((guess_x, guess_y), light)

        if not any([intersect(*e, *light_guess_line) for e in edges]):
            num_successes += 1
    return float(num_successes / num_sims) * (xr * yr)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    points = [
    (1/2, 18),
    (1,3),
    (5,1/2),
    (7,5),
    (12,7),
    (16,3),
    (15,11),
    (8,19),
    (3,7)
    ]
    light_source = (5,8)
    print("Area lit by light: %f"% lit_area(light_source, points))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZHbbtswDIbv9RRcgaKkyqFRg7apBw9I05s@g@EVysGJAFs25AOSvXxGOTs484XI/wN/iqKbU3eo/fx8LkJdQbB@K8FVTR06rfq0966oQ6U2aWmr9dbCkt94leAqM/nXpRyk8S2bxXyW03fJ//HVX64@ruz8nmxwGSN9STc4EpKbIVJRI43ZO6ntrgCLJQ/s01etn7lNZ5Qo2P/p6BKsnMdj5nKZFI7gPAzElT3@z0hBVJ@i7o532ksXOKSIPeo9zoh4TAxJVtK39j61/oTZB@qC9YGitYiNStd2@NM1OPCQmSS/zwZ5Y06U0w@jIOy6Pni06xZj17iDMcaVXKD5Dc0ISRdlbTtsHzydm9r5roUUMpnt8qF5eGQwC@IJ4vlUPrHUTMELP12VP/LLlX6@9htpYKZgweZ1qufiH1WuSrc/dJ9t3YfNTuaUuxekmiBj480y7Kysp4P1Cca6BG6Lm9v4/yYuhssric6/AA)

[Credit for line intersection algorithm](https://bryceboe.com/2006/10/23/line-segment-intersection-algorithm/)

Also, credit to all the helpful commenters on how to golf this even further.

Comment: The first line can become `from random import*` (line break) `u=uniform` for -2 bytes

Comment: you can shave some more bytes by replacing each of the 4 spaces in the function with a single space, and remove the space after `g=lambda i:`

Comment: Does `n` have to be a power of 10? Otherwise you can save a byte by using a power of 9.

Comment: No, powers of 10 are not required. I’ll put in all of your suggestions tomorrow!  Until then, happy Valentine’s Day everyone!

Comment: As _@ConorO'Brien_ mentioned, you can remove loads of leading whitespaces. And in addition to the space at `i:(min`, the space at `x[i]for` can be removed as well. Also, `return float(s/n)*(r*t)` can be `return(r*t)*float(s/n)`. And I'm not entirely sure, but can't the variables `r` and `e` be removed and used directly, since you only use them once? It somehow does give a slightly different result even though `g` isn't modified, so that part confuses me a bit (I'm not too familiar with Python to understand why the result is slightly different).

Comment: Actually, it's different due to the random, duh.. So the `e` and `r` variables can be removed, and the `abs(g(0)[0]-g(0)[1])` and `list(zip(v,v[1:]+[v[0]]))` can be used directly.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen The result will change with each run regardless of changes to the code. This is due to the use of the random number generator.

Comment: @JPeroutek Yeah, I realized that shortly after my first comment, hence the second comment. :)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Sorry, Stack app doesn’t automatically reload comments :) thanks for the feedback

Comment: Putting it all together, it's [**419 bytes**](https://tio.run/##XZLdboMwDIXveQqv0iSHeRpZ1bVDYlLX3ewZEJrSFtpsEFAIqN3Ldw7dDx0Xcc4Xn8S2aI5uX5vp6VTYugKrzJaDrpraOuiMLmpbgWqhC7Z5AQpL6kUcwCYpVbXeKljSM61iXKUyu13yIkJ8TiO/jzLxxPs/vvrlAbxe@Okl3uDSR3GVbHAggisBT1kN1O9e2Lr7seoYK23wkOqMq4QDaAO9oEod/jN2mURGYTgLoE2iAPzZmz/jfnc5Gt8SvCcdhjuMfDp8nIUcxD5BfKcPQaVXugBTO1DmiOkrhgWFe@EvLPyFpW4dfuoGe@pTGWc3ac8dZ0JkIm5vEhmAzV1nDRRlrRy2d0aEat2if8rPZ4h@XGcYfcNogKem1sa1kEDKdZw/lHf3BHIhaIRoOpYz4pwxmNPsIv2e5hf64dIv@QI5BguSj2M9Zf@gsqDUu717a@vObnKuk99eiKCxXDZOljZXPCAH6yMMeTFcF5Nr/1eNXATnLoU4fQE)

Comment: Would it be legal to pull my variable `n` into the parameters, and have it specified when the function is called?  Or does that go against the rules?

Comment: [409 bytes](https://tio.run/##XZHbTuMwEEDf/RWzSEgzwStqKqAEGamUF74hipDbJq0hcSLHiVp@vjtO95KuHzwzx3N3ewz7xs1Pp9I3NXjjtixs3TY@JKLXvbNl42ux0ZWp11sDS/kqVymuMpX/XPJFCb5ms6jPcnph/R9f/eXi/SJcvqUbXEZJP/QGR0JcGSJla6RReyOxLUowWMmBUgG7P2lsirV1eMhszu3BAayDgWRtDv8zenb6KUkenjs9ExAfPuIDD7or0MWk8Kl7THY4Y9@vs6pY3WvET/lFsiL2sSW4JoBxR8zeMSllsqeYrIzJKtsF/LYtDnLIVJrfZANPnRPllHY3WgnwRei9Q7PuMBaKixll3NMZqt9QjZCSsmpMwO7W0altrAsdaMi4kfNBdXsnQS1ITpCcT817yT5T8CjvL9zv5OOF/XAZrziBmoKFVE9Te87xo5WLyu724aNrer8puE@uvSDRem4br5a@MLyhAOsjjH4pXJdX1/FTJ1ESzlMSnX4B "Python 3 – Try It Online") by combining variable declarations

Comment: @JPeroutek you can pull your definitions in the parameters and assign default values. With this you get Stephen's suggestion to 408 bytes:

Comment: [TIO](https://tio.run/##XZFfT@MwDMDf@yl8SEh2MWJhAkZRThrjhc9QVSjb2i3QplWbVtt9@Z3TcXfd5SG2f/H/NEe/r938dCrauoLWuK0IWzV16@Oo172zRd1W0UaXplpvDSz5lVcJrlKV3S7lohhf01nQZxn9FP0fX/3l0ftFOL8lG1wGST/0BkdCUhkCFWukQXujaJsXYLDkgXd/ctgEK@vwkNpMeoMDWAcDcWUO/zNip5/j@JE7PaMkgvD0EZ5kzl2OLjD41D3GO5wRvXydVSXqXiN@8hdxSeJjC3C1B@OOmL5jXHC8p5CsCMlK23n8ZRsceEhVkt2kgwydEWWUdDdaRdDmvm8dmnWHoVDYyyjDms5QfUM1QoqLsjYeuztHp6a2znegIZVGzgfV3T2DWhBPEM@n5gOLzxQ88cOF@z0/XdiPl/FKEqgpWLB6ntpziR@tLCrtbu8/urpvN7n0KbUXFDWttI1XyzY3siEP6yOMfglcF1fX4U8nUQznKYlOvwE)

Comment: `if not any([I(*f,*h)for f in list(zip(v,v[1:]+[v[0]]))]):s+=1` can become `s+=any([I(*f,*h)for f in list(zip(v,v[1:]+[v[0]]))])^1` to save 7 bytes.

Comment: `for _ in range(n):` can become `for _ in'x'*n:` to save 4 bytes.

Comment: `j=u(*g(0));k=u(*g(1));h=((j,k),l)` can become `h=(u(*g(0)),u(*g(1))),l` to save 10 bytes.

Answer (score 5):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 559 <sub><sup><s>618</s> <s>632</s></sup></sub> bytes

```hs
r(a:b)=b++[a]
s=zip<*>r
(?)a=sum.zipWith(*)a
o(a,b)=r a?b-a?r b
(a,b)!(c,d)=(c-a,d-b)
(a,b)#(c,d)=a*d-b*c
x i a@(e,f)b j c d|let k@(g,h)=a!b;l=c!d;m=c!a;n=l#k;o=m#l/n;p=m#k/n;q|i>0=o<0||o>1|let=o<=0||o>=1;r|n==0||q||p<0||p*j>1=[]|let=[(e+o*g,f+o*h)]=r
(a&b)(c:e@(d:_))|let(f,g)=span(/=d)b;h=zip f$r$f++[d]=concat[[k,l]|(i,j)<-h,[[k],[l]]<-[x 1 i j 0 a<$>[c,d]],and[x 0 m n 1 a o==[]|o<-[k,l],(m,n)<-h,(m,n)/=(i,j)]]++(a&g)e
(_&_)_=[]
z a b=sum[o$unzip[c,a,d]|e@(f:_)<-[[c|c<-b,and[all(==c)$x 1 d e 1 a c|(d,e)<-s b]]],(c,d)<-s$a&until((f==).head)r b$e++[f]]/2
```

Exact solution (barring bugs). Haskell has built-in exact rational arithmetic. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVHbbqMwEH3nK6YpquzENECbXpI47XtXWmn3YR@QFRkwgYRgCkRbVfx7duxclO4uD8zMmTNnLs5lu1Flud83RE5jyuPRKJLCaflnUc@Hi8YhL1Tydre9ReBX0eVkSKWjiWRIbkC@xJ58aSB2LHJFEpZSThJPstSL6QG9PqByiNAwcT6gAPlKFMtoDGtIIO1L1cHmlaxYjrSreFby5CqdbfEvZxUvrzczzbfX5bia1Wg3aN/7YuFzPff7Xi8CI4ABtxEPZk1fcRO8931tKPVwvQh4JCwvImqkhyuW4T@nguOO8iamJJmqV5JOl5QaGsnYivK2lhUZ85TGs9ycBDK3cTO8USp4oqtEdlG0YaXoScHWdO7lDGPBolKIuRd9QIC7rsEHOXcXEV5BCCarFBM@bKHCtATNzWAa6UaIkS2rrJB1xtwKCzEa4ZArqhyyvFnSJZY4n1gcm6eJtLurcDhsgGcXPa6R4RqoGCV9Mvdi21OWJeE8oa6ZKgVlmyc9SZlCaguxwOHsS2Hkyptd1RUlIRnn9DZXMqX4yq7C1TMhxuF@K4sKuANg3i7JVbKBsljlHdS6qLoWGtXuyg44pBpJh89QG4Q@v1KnU/ghu0JXsjxT6133s2u@VeDCwNKmMIDRCNpc/z5WYzRg0Gi9vcwdNP@rIxslL6mN8UiRmZn4aeAuVxVyyPc3OgBVtsoE6qNWSafSI@mLiEXovw0HA8TwRqk@nof4DHwKEfECBl5AGZBLx1rPOgLuz3rH2gmDJ1MbjEMWPB1K7oyZMISM88gmFg7Zo7UPh3yABCv9xIJnY@8wLzAMJpPwbvzwGPj072Yhg9A0swMbjUvHdglPiHFC/9jI5M5aXz9bGljiw8mxkJ397Nyfcgc2zhnePz@Pw5Du/wA)

Note that this gives `815523/6710`, not `814643/6710`, for the example room, and the first wall intersection is calculated as `(55/61, 363/61)`. I'm fairly sure this is correct because the Monte Carlo entry (slowly) converges to the same result.

Legend:

```hs
z light roomPoints
    -- Main function, returns lit area.
    -- Compute list of visible corners in the room, then calls (&).
(&) light roomPoints' visibleCorners
    -- Compute visibility polygon. visibleCorners is the subset of points
    -- that are visible from the light. The first point of roomPoints'
    -- must coincide with the first visibleCorner.
x pEndpoints p1 p2 qSegment q1 q2
    -- Intersect line segments (p1, p2) and (q1, q2).
    -- If pEndpoints, exclude endpoints p1, p2.
    -- If not qSegment, allow intersection to extend past q2 (i.e. raycast).
r   -- Rotate list by one, used to construct closed loops etc.
s   -- Construct closed loop
(!) -- Vector between two points
(?) -- Dot product
(#) -- Cross product
o   -- Polygon area
```

Bonus: [Gloss](http://gloss.ouroborus.net/) GUI for testing. Click next to points to move them.

```hs
import qualified Graphics.Gloss as G
import qualified Graphics.Gloss.Interface.IO.Interact as GI

solnPoly a b|let c@(d:_)=[c|c<-b,and[all(==c)$x 1 d e 1 a c|(d,e)<-s b]]=a&until((d==).head)r b$c++[d]
solnArea = z

main =
  let fromRatP (x, y) = (fromRational x, fromRational y)
      displayScale = 10
      scalePoints = G.scale (fromInteger displayScale) (fromInteger displayScale)
      displayMode = G.InWindow "" (512, 512) (0, 0)
      drawBasePoly pointSz ps =
          mconcat $ G.lineLoop ps :
                    [G.translate x y (G.circleSolid pointSz) | (x, y) <- ps]
      drawVisPolyOf light ps =
          G.color G.blue $ drawBasePoly 0.2 $ map fromRatP $ solnPoly light ps
      drawLight (x, y) =
          G.translate x y $
          G.color G.yellow (G.circleSolid 0.5) <> G.circle 0.5
      draw (light, ps) =
          mconcat [
              scalePoints $ drawLight (fromRatP light),
              scalePoints $ drawBasePoly 0.4 (map fromRatP ps),
              scalePoints $ drawVisPolyOf light ps,
              G.translate (-200) (-50) $ G.scale 0.2 0.2 $
                G.color G.blue $ G.text $ "Lit area: " ++ show (solnArea light ps)
          ]
      event (GI.EventKey (GI.MouseButton GI.LeftButton) GI.Down _ (curx_, cury_)) (light, ps) =
          let dist (x,y) (x',y') = (x'-x)^2 + (y'-y)^2
              curx = curx_ / fromInteger displayScale
              cury = cury_ / fromInteger displayScale
              cursorR = (fromInteger$round curx, fromInteger$round cury)
              maxDist = 3
              snapAmount = 1
              (d, i) = minimum [(dist p cursorR, i) | (p, i) <- zip (light : ps) [0..]]
              snapTo n a = fromInteger$n*round(a/fromInteger n)
              snapCursor = (snapTo snapAmount curx, snapTo snapAmount cury)
              light' | i == 0 && d < maxDist^2 = snapCursor
                     | otherwise = light
              ps' | i > 0 && d < maxDist^2 = take (i-1) ps ++ [snapCursor] ++ drop i ps
                  | otherwise = ps
          in (light', ps')
      event _ state = state
      state0 =
        ((2, 2), [(0, 0), (10, 0), (10, 5), (20, 0), (20, 20), (15, 5),
                  (10, 10), (6, 10), (10, 12), (0, 12), (4, 10), (0, 10)])
  in G.play displayMode G.white 60
            state0
            draw
            event
            (\_ -> id)
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Actually, you’re right. I must have made a typo lol. Will update those numbers slightly

Answer (score 1):

## APL+WIN

This is an ungolfed version of this interesting challenge which I offer to demonstrate my logic. My ancient version of APL+WIN is not well suited to golfing nested control structures. More modern APLs could well do better - challenge?

If readers validate the logic I will have a go at golfing this solution. If the logic is wrong I will simply delete.

```
r←b Room v

⍝Separate x and y coordinates of vertices               
x←v[;1] ⋄ y←v[;2]

⍝Intercept and slope of each line segment and ray through each vertex
s←(y,¨1⌽y)⌹¨(1E¯9+1,[1.1]¨x,¨1⌽1E¯9+x)
l←(y,¨b[2])⌹¨(1E¯9+1,[1.1]¨x,¨b[1]+1E¯9)                          

⍝Coordinates of vertices
x←x,¨1⌽x ⋄ y←y,¨1⌽y                                                  

⍝Initialise intersection matrix
r←((⍴s),0)⍴0

⍝Evaluate intersection matrix 
:for i :in ⍳⍴l 
    t←0⍴0
    :for j :in ⍳⍴s
        t←t,⍎1⍕∊((↑∊l[i])-↑∊s[j])÷((1↓∊s[j])-1↓∊l[i]) 
    :endfor
    z←r←r,t
:endfor 

⍝Identify x coordinates of valid intersections in the direction of the ray
:for i :in ⍳⍴l 
    t←(r[i;i])
    :for j :in ⍳⍴s
        :if t<b[1] 
            r[j;i]←r[j;i]×(r[j;i]<t)^r[j;i]>⌊/∊x[i]
        :else
            r[j;i]←r[j;i]×(r[j;i]>t)^r[j;i]<⌈/∊x[i]
        :endif
    :endfor
 :endfor

⍝Identify the edges intersected
e←(+/r≠0)/⍳⍴l 

⍝Intersection x coordinates
cx←(+/r)[e]

⍝Intersection y coordinates
cy←⍎1⍕+/¨(s[e])× 1,¨(+/r)[e]

⍝Replace original coordinates that are in shadow
x[e]←(1↓¨x[e]),¨cx
y[e]←(1↓¨y[e]),¨cy

⍝Calculate lit area
r←+/.5×(|-/¨x)×|-/¨y
```

Answer (score 0):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>296</s> 255 bytes

```r
function(s,l,u=cbind(s,s[,1]),d=t(diff(t(u))),q=l-u,r=apply(s,1,range),g=c(diff(r)))mean(replicate(1e6,!any((q[i<-1:ncol(s)*2]*(p=runif(2)*g+r[1,]-u)[j<-i-1]>p[i]*q[j])!=(q[i+2]*p[i+1]>q[i+1]*p[i+2])&(p[i]*d[j]>p[j]*d[i])!=(q[i]*d[j]>q[j]*d[i]))))*prod(g)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PZDLboQwDEX3fAWzqWwwqgKaGVqR/gjKgvJSUBogwGK@nprXZJNj@9xEiVsbP4vWZrHlrHsLExlaZPmrbcU85SQUUiVnqHTTwAwLItIoTbSQk8UwmBdrglxh2xqpleUhOtb@6sKCqwejy2KuQdQJ3Qr7AhhznUXi25a9gQmDWAUwSLdY3UCMQRu6XJCKFsy7LNKRUD9DrlUw5p3Cm9zSIUe4F/Jo3Le9ihV@wK5WrHKo20hfobM9vtu8gsH1FbS4TvwJ/vFqz/dLEJ8x@SJFOipKTroTT05@0v2ax/S88PF2Bcvi5JTE14kJux56Zr@RD/RT9Jrt33H9Bw)

This is a further reduced version of the [Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/179946/42248). The core Monte Carlo method is the same, but I rearranged some of the functions to make them shorter. In my first iteration, I'd been over-aggressive in rearrangement, and I then realised I could optimise both length and speed by returning to a version of the intersection algorithm closer to the python.

Here's an ungolfed version that also plots the results:

```r
find_lit_ungolf <- function(shape, light, plot = TRUE) {
  lines <- cbind(shape ,shape[,1])
  diffs <- t(diff(t(lines)))
  light_minus_lines <- light - lines
  shape_range <- apply(s,1,range)
  shape_range_diff <- c(diff(shape_range))
  successes <- t(replicate(
    n = 1e5,
    {
      random_point <- runif(2) * shape_range_diff + shape_range[1, ]
      random_minus_lines <- random_point - lines
      q <- light_minus_lines
      p <- random_minus_lines
      d <- diffs
      i <- 1:ncol(s)*2
      success <-
        !any((q[i]*p[i-1]>p[i]*q[i-1])!=(q[i+2]*p[i+1]>q[i+1]*p[i+2])&(p[i]*d[i-1]>p[i-1]*d[i])!=(q[i]*d[i-1]>q[i-1]*d[i]))
      c(random_point, success)
    }))
  colnames(successes) <- c("x", "y", "success")
  if (plot) {
    shape <- t(shape)
    colnames(shape) <- c("x", "y")
    print(ggplot(as_tibble(successes), aes(x, y)) +
      geom_point(aes(colour = factor(success)), alpha = 0.3) +
      geom_polygon(data = as_tibble(shape), alpha = 0.2) +
      annotate("point", light[1], light[2], col = "yellow"))
  }
  mean(successes[, 3]) * prod(shape_range_diff)
}
find_lit_ungolf(s, l)
```

[image: Plot of light in room]